# Controlling file size while exporting data from bigquery to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am working on exporting large dataset from bigquery to Goolge cloud storage into the compressed format. In Google cloud storage I have file size limitation( maximum file size 1GB each file). Therefore I am using split and compassion techniques to split data while exporting. The sample code is as follow:

```
gcs_destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'wikipedia-*.csv.gz') 
gcs_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

# Job Config
job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.compression = bigquery.Compression.GZIP

def bigquery_datalake_load():  
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)  # API Request
    row_count = table.num_rows

    extract_job = bigquery_client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        gcs_destination_uri,
        location='US',
        job_config=job_config)  # API request
    logging.info('BigQuery extract Started.... Wait for the job to complete.')
    extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

    print('Exported {}:{}.{} to {}'.format(
        project, dataset_id, table_id, gcs_destination_uri))
    # [END bigquery_extract_table]
```

This code is splitting the large dataset and compressing into `.gz` format but it is returning multiple compressed files which size is rounding between 40MB to 70MB.

I am trying to generate the compressed file with the size of 1GB (each file). Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no - Google adjust it by itself - you do not have options to specify size.
I believe it is because of size of uncompressed data (so each BQ worker produced one file and it is impossible to produce one file from multiple workers)

Comment: Hi Alexey  - Thanks for the answer. Can you please help me to understand how export works internally and worker produce file?

Comment: I am not a google employee :) - but I speak a lot with BQ eng - so I think idea when you doing something in BQ - it try to parallelize it as much as it can by splitting between multiple machines - it is why BQ is so fast and it is also why you sometimes get resource exceeded - when BQ can not split data based on you criteria.

Comment: When you do export - exactly the same happened - all your data divided between multiple machines and each machine produce file and stream to gzip - and probably everything happened in RAM. So now imagine 1GB of gziped file can be 100s GB uncompressed - in this case everything will be very slow - but in the same time different data may have different compression ratio - so it is difficult to predict final size of the file - so specifying target size will ruin overall system speed

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. You need to know the total size of your export and knowing this you can split the results using Multiple wildcard URIs. {1}

For example, if your export is 10GB you can define 10 wildcard URIs and they will be 1GB  of size aprox.

You have a similar question answered here: {2}

{1}: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files

{2}: [Exporting data to GCS from BigQuery - Split file size control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334241/exporting-data-to-gcs-from-bigquery-split-file-size-control)

Comment: I do not think it will work with gzip as was asked. It will just produced the same 40-70MB but with name having 00..xx for shards

Comment: In my case, I am trying to create a utility that will run for multiple dataset and tables. I guess it will fail if we don't know the data size. Please correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As other members commented, it is not possible. I think this issue more than having to deal with a google specific algorithm, it deals with the question of whether or not compressed files could have its compressed size calculated before doing it's actual compression and the answer is not.

Because all compression techniques do make use of some sort of dictionary, the final size of any file is known only after all symbols had been translated, which means the compression has been done. There is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572430/how-to-estimate-zip-file-size-in-java-before-creating-it) of SO in which this is discussed, and this [article](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/file-compression1.htm) does explain some fundamentals about compression.

Files could be "padded" in order to make them of a uniform bigger size, but that would defeat the objective of compression (which is of saving space).