# File Compression to fixed size In Java

Tags: java, zip, compression

I want to perform file compression using `zip` package of `java.util` library. The aim is to limit the compressed file to a fixed size. If the compressed file size is greater than this limit, it should be split into multiple files.

```
try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(p_request.getOutputFilePath() + zipFileName);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            zipEntry1 = new ZipEntry(f.getName());
            fis = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
            int count;
            while ((count = fis.read(fileRAW, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
              zipEntry1 = new ZipEntry(f.getName());
              if (currentSize >= (p_request.getMaxSizePerFileInMB() * 1024 * 1024)) {
                zipSplitCount++;
                zos.close();
                zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    p_request.getOutputFilePath() + zipFileName
                        + "_" + zipSplitCount + ".zip"));
                currentSize = 0;
              }
              zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry1);
//              zos.closeEntry();
              currentSize += zipEntry1.getCompressedSize();
              zos.write(fileRAW, 0, count);
            }
```

I always get compressed size as -1. Can someone advise a clean approach for this?

EDIT:

So I compressed the file into chunks of fixed size to get multi parts compressed zip of the same file as f.1.zip, f.2.zip. Now when I decompress it, is there some way to restore the original file? Currently, it says the file must be broken.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER];
        ZipInputStream zis = null;
        try {
          zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath()));
          ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();

          while(zipEntry!=null){

            String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
            File newFile = new File(p_request.getOutputFilePath() + fileName);

            System.out.println("file unzip : "+ newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

            new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
              fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            fos.close();
            zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
          }

          zis.closeEntry();
          zis.close();
```

Comment: Re edit, show the code.

Comment: Added. Please check the question again.

Comment: @user207421 any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting -1 because the size is not known until the Zip file has been written to disk. Compression takes place when you save the entire zip file, not when you add a new entry.

This means that you have to either:

- write the zip to disk after adding each file and then measuring the zip to determine whether to keep adding to it or creating a new file
- or *guesstimate* the size based on an average compression rate and the size of the file before compression on disk.

Comment: but if I write to disk, i will need to close the stream. I can not process the future files in the directory.
zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry1);
zos.write(fileRAW, 0, count);
zos.close();
currentSize += zipEntry1.getCompressedSize();

Comment: Check to see whether you get the size back before closing the stream. If not, yes, you'll have to close it and open it again... Yes it's expensive. Alternatively, why not generate a single zip file and then split it?

Comment: See if this thread helps you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572430/how-to-estimate-zip-file-size-in-java-before-creating-it

Comment: @DavidBrossard Is that possible? Splitting zip